# How to evaluate the complex logarithms $\log(i)$ and $\log(3+4i)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

How to evaluate $$\log(i)?$$
Also, how to evaluate $$\log(3+4i)?$$
I am reading complex analysis and I know that logarithm is a multibranched function and is periodic. What I have for the definition is $$\log(z) = \log(\rho)+i(\theta +2k\pi).$$
That is for when $z$ is complex.
I also have, $\log(z)=\log|z|+i(\arg(z)+2k\pi)$
I don't know where to start, so please write a detailed and step-by-step solution if you can, thank you very much!

Comment: You could start by computing $|i|$ and $\text{arg}(i)$.

Comment: Can you explain how to do so? I have no examples in this book, just the derivation....Sorry if im asking too much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polar form $a+ib$ ($a$ and $b$ real) is $re^{i\theta}$ where $r= \sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}$ and $\theta =\arctan \frac b a$ (which is taken as $\pi /2$ if $a=0$ and $b >0$, as $-\pi /2$ if $a=0$ and $b <0$).

This gives $i=e^{i\pi /2}$ and $3+4i=5e^{i\arctan (4/3)}$. Now from the definition of logarithm we get $\log i=i\pi /2+2k\pi i$ and $\log (3+4i)= \ln 5+i\arctan (\frac 4 3) +2k \pi i$.

Comment: We took $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for the $\log(i)$ case because it was $arctan\frac{1}{0}$ right ?

Comment: Yes, this is the case where $a=0$ and $b>0$. @VukStojiljkovic

Comment: Might i ask, why is it $\arctan\frac{b}{a}$ for the angle?  Just wondering. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic $\theta$ is the angle made by the line joining $0$ and $a+ib$ with the positive $x-axis$.  The slope of this line is $\frac b a$ and it is also $\tan (\theta)$. So $\tan (\theta)=\frac  b a$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer sir, have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that:

$$\log(z) = \log(\rho)+i(\theta +2k\pi),$$

where $z = \rho e^{i\theta}.$

When $z = i$, then $z = e^{i\frac{pi}{2}}$. Hence, $\rho = 1$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Finally:

$$\log(i) = \log(1) + i \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k \pi\right) = \frac{i\pi}{2}(1 + 4k). $$

When $z = 3+4i$, we have that $\rho = \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = 5$ and $\theta = \arctan \left(\frac{4}{3}\right).$

Hence:

$$\log(3+4i) = \log(5) + i \left(\arctan \left(\frac{4}{3}\right) + 2k \pi\right). $$